# Routes for multiple users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website, xyz.com and users are setting up admin accounts where they then have other users that are registering under them.  They call their account name `wisconsinsponsor`.  Another user sets up another account called `iowasponsor`.   So I want to be able to have the ability that a user could browse to `xyz.com/wisconsinsponsor` and `xyz.com/iowasponsor` and get funneled into the appropriate settings that these users have setup.

So then after I browse to `xyz.com/wisconsinsponsor` which will allow me to get the appropriate settings for wisconsinsponsor I can be dropped onto `xyz.com/wisconsinsponsor/{controller}/{method}`.

So I added the following code.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    List<Sponsor> sponsors = new SponsorContext().Sponsors.ToList();

    foreach (Sponsor sponsor in sponsors)
    {
        // ALL THE PROPERTIES:
        // rentalProperties/
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: sponsor.SponsorName,
            url: sponsor.SponsorName + "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = sponsor.SponsorId
            }
        );
    }


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

So the main goal is that without logging in, I can get information that pertains to each "sponsor" and then just generic information if a user goes to 'xyz.com' without specifying a sponsor.  The below works to a point for landing on the home page, but then when I navigate to login or any other view, I get for example 'xyz.com/[my first sponsor entry in the database]/admin/login' instead of 'xyz.com/admin/login'.  Why doesn't the navigation fall to the Default route?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reverse the variable in the url.

xyz.com/{adminAccountVariable}/{controller}/{method}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace Example
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "admin",
                url: "{id}/RoutingConstraintExample/{action}/",
                defaults: new { controller = "RoutingConstraintExample", action = "Index", id = 0 },
                constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 0 },
                constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

**This is how I think the problem should be handled.**

Owin is a more recent form of authentication. Use security to restrict access to the admin pages. Owin or other forms of security can be used to identify which user is logged in. Use the identified user to control what settings are used in the admin pages.

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/owin-and-katana

Use a database to save admin user profile settings. This will work for keeping track of profile subtypes similar to the adminaccount and admin2account shown in the original question. The Controller and action will be the same but the application will know which parts of the view to show based on if the database returned a adminaccount type or an admin2account type for the person logged into the website.

Comment: I want to treat the Id as a subdomain?  Will this work for that?

Comment: It will allow you to group by a variable or a number of variables. You might want to avoid using this approach and find away to achieve your goal using a form of authentication.